# Woocommerce checkout showing 1 column...can't seem to get default 2 back?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, multiple-columns, checkout

Having the oddest dilemma.  I've modified the rest of my site pretty extensively with custom css coding for my theme.  The rest of my site is fine, but things get thrown off in my checkout page since the upgrade to the latest version of wordpress.

In any case, you can see what's going on here:

https://sportsautotech.com/checkout/

As you can see, both the 'billing and shipping' box fields and 'your order' box fields are below each other in 1 column.

I'd like them side by side as indicated in the attached picture.

I currently have no custom css inserted for this checkout page. I've tried adding custom css code as suggested by other posters through google searches, but none seem to work and actually make things worse.

If I can get that solved, does anyone have any suggestion on how to fix the other 2 smaller issues with the State field indentation and Phone number field dropping down a line?

Thanks so much for any potential help!  Please refer below.

Images:

[currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gedv7.jpg)

[desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePGea.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achive your target result past the below css in your style.css or in the WordPress customiser :

```
.row-fluid .span6 {
width: 46.93617% !important;
}

#billing_postcode_field{
float: left;
width: 45%;
}

#billing_phone_field {
width: 50%;
float: right;
}

#billing_state_field, {
float: unset !important;
 }

 .payment_method_stripe{
margin-top: 3rem
}
```

OutPut:

[image]

Comment: ...thank you SO much! It's getting me very close, but for some odd reason Chrome (latest version) is still showing that single column layout and it didn't change much of anything that I could notice (odd). Firefox (latest version as well), however, looks just like your output as it should.  Any possible ideas?  I'm curious what browser you were using to attain your own screencap?  Again, I can't thank you enough for your help...this had me pulling out my hair all day!

Comment: @BEncarnacion did u add those css so i can check them on your site?

Comment: Indeed, my friend...the exact code has been added to the css custom coding section (at the bottom so none of my other previous customizations would override).  Just odd how it's giving me different outputs on different browsers, but I suppose that can happen sometimes.

Comment: @BEncarnacion i will check it

Comment: You are awesome.  Absolutely no rush, I'm about to take a nap as I've been working on this all day and am spent, but I shall check back later in the morning.  Thank you again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @BEncarnacion i just checked it actually it's working fine you just need to clear your browser cache i can see only the State field is not aligned correctly yet

Comment: You, my friend, are a savior! I had thought I'd cleared my cache yesterday (using cccleaner) but it appears it didn't take effect.  I'll find a way to figure out those other small issues, but I REALLY appreciate your help.  Thank you again!!

Comment: So sorry, my friend, but one last quick question if it's within the scope of your abilities.  Is there a way to add a custom bolded text, ex: 'Order make take a few moments to process. Please do not refresh the page or press back on your browser after placing your order.' right below the 'save payment information' checkbox field? I'd ideally like to keep it within the grayed stripe payment box.  Thank you again!

Comment: Yes of course it’s possible please put on another question I will answer u ASAP